# inserting html code in php file

Tags: php

I have a file, contact.php. Which i want it to display a contact form upon evaluating a cookie variable. the code is shown below:

```
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['a12cookie']) { ?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><strong>Contact Form </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td width="16%">Subject</td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
<td width="82%"><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Detail</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="4" id="detail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset"         name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php }>
```

i get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/looksr5/public_html/contact.php on line 1
```

Apologies if its an obvious mistake, as im still new to php. Also im using this instead of echoing every single HTML line. Please tell me where i have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And don't forget the closing `?>` at the end of the file (you don't have the question mark)

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['a12cookie']) { ?>
```

Should be

```
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['a12cookie'])) { ?>
```

i.e. you were missing the second `)` before the `{`.

Answer (score 4):

First, I am glad you are actually developing with error display being on.  Many new developers could spend hours trying to figure out a problem that could have solved in minutes or seconds with the error message on.

Second, you should begin to understand the error messages. Usually, you find find they mean exactly what they say, and will give you a very good hint on how to solve the error.  In the case, the message is indicating that the parser came across an opening bracket that it wasn't expecting and tell you the exact line of code where the problem occurred - your first line of code.  That means that should be the first place you should look.

Usually a message of this sort occurs because you didn't properly close out parenthesis or previous brackets, which is the case here in that you didn't close out your parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `)` in here `<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['a12cookie']) { ?>`